# MFC CListCtrl CustomDraw() event handler code getting stuck

Tags: c++, mfc, paint, clistctrl, custom-draw

I'm currently experiencing a problem with my OnNMCustomdrawlistctrlvalues() event handler being called non-stop once I've painted a CListCtrl row red (code gets stuck), causing my application to freeze once I try to perform another event, such as clicking a button.

I have the following code:

```
void CSPID_FQA_Test_ClientDlg::OnNMCustomdrawlistctrlvalues(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW lpLVCustomDraw = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);
    int itemCnt = 0;
    CString text;
    RECT rc;

    switch(lpLVCustomDraw->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
    case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
    case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT | CDDS_SUBITEM:
        //get each row text for 2nd column
        itemCnt = mListCtrl.GetItemCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCnt; i++)
        {
            text = mListCtrl.GetItemText(i, 2);
            if (text.Compare("No") == 0)
            {
                if (i == (lpLVCustomDraw->nmcd.dwItemSpec))
                {
                    lpLVCustomDraw->clrTextBk = RGB(255,50,50);
                    mListCtrl.GetItemRect(i,&rc,LVIR_BOUNDS);
                    mListCtrl.InvalidateRect(&rc, 0);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    default: break;
    }

    *pResult = 0;
    *pResult |= CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
    *pResult |= CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;
    *pResult |= CDRF_NOTIFYPOSTPAINT;
}
```

Which results in:

[image: result1]

Within the CListCtrl, if I scroll to an area which isn't painted red, my application is fine.

I'm not too sure how to stop this from happening... maybe I need an alternative way of dynamically painting a row red?

---

**EDIT:** I have changed my code to the below, but am experiencing this issue (only 2nd and 3rd column being coloured, but when I redraw the list control i.e. scroll down then back up, all columns are then drawn):

[image: result2]

```
void CSPID_FQA_Test_ClientDlg::OnNMCustomdrawlistctrlvalues(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW lpLVCustomDraw = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);
    int itemCnt = 0;
    CString text;
    RECT rc;

    CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle (lpLVCustomDraw->nmcd.hdc);

    switch(lpLVCustomDraw->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
    case CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT:
    //case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
    //case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT | CDDS_SUBITEM:
        //get each row text for 2nd column
        itemCnt = mListCtrl.GetItemCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCnt; i++)
        {
            text = mListCtrl.GetItemText(i, 2);
            if (text.Compare("No") == 0)
            {
                if (i == (lpLVCustomDraw->nmcd.dwItemSpec))
                {
                    //lpLVCustomDraw->clrTextBk = RGB(255,50,50);
                    mListCtrl.GetItemRect(i,&rc,LVIR_BOUNDS);
                    pDC->FillSolidRect (&rc, RGB (0, 255, 0));

                    //mListCtrl.InvalidateRect(&rc, 0);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    default: break;
    }

    *pResult = 0;
    *pResult |= CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
    *pResult |= CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;
    *pResult |= CDRF_NOTIFYPOSTPAINT;
}
```

---

**EDIT2:** I changed to the below code, but am still getting the same issue:

```
LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW lpLVCustomDraw = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);
CString text;
RECT rc;

CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle (lpLVCustomDraw->nmcd.hdc);

switch(lpLVCustomDraw->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
{
case CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT:

    mListCtrl.GetItemRect(lpLVCustomDraw->nmcd.dwItemSpec,&rc,LVIR_BOUNDS);
    text = mListCtrl.GetItemText(lpLVCustomDraw->nmcd.dwItemSpec, 2);

    if (text.Compare("No") == 0)
    {
        pDC->FillSolidRect (&rc, RGB(0, 0, 255));
    }

    break;
default: break;
}
```

[image: result3]

Comment: This code is being called as part of the drawing of a list item; by calling `InvalidateRect` you cause the drawing to be performed again. Infinite loop!

Comment: Hi @MarkRansom, thanks for the reply! Ahhh of course. I commented out the `InvalidateRect` line and it has stopped freezing. I get the following result upon drawing (but correctly redraws if I scroll down and back up again) - http://i.imgur.com/umiH6zI.png
Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: If I knew how to fix it, I'd have left an answer instead of a comment. A little experimenting should lead you to a solution.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRansom. I'm still playing around with it to find a fix. Cheers.

Comment: Hi again @MarkRansom, still haven't found a solution yet - kind of messing around aimlessly. Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I think your design is slightly off by using CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT.  I use custom painting to highlight a row in a CListCtrl to the color yellow.  I do this by leveraging **CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT** and using the *FillSolidRect* and *DrawText* methods of the CDC.  As Mark alluded to, some simple experimenting (with what I've posted in this answer) should help.

**Edit**: Using CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT, you can get the device context by

```
CDC*  pDC = CDC::FromHandle (pNMLVCD->nmcd.hdc);
```

Getting the row corodinates that you want to paint can be done by

```
GetItemRect (row, &rect, LVIR_BOUNDS);
```

Rendering the row color is done by

```
pDC->FillSolidRect (&rect, RGB (0, 255, 0));
```

And, lastly, draw each column text by

```
//  draw each column's text into the corresponding CRect.
for (col=0; col<nCols; ++col)
    {
    GetSubItemRect (row, col, LVIR_BOUNDS, rect);
    rect.left += 6;
    CString text = pRow->GetColumnText (col);
    pDC->DrawText (text, &rect, DT_LEFT | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
    }
```

You'll need to make the necessary adjustments to the above code to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Are you able to share some code snippets?

Comment: Thanks for that! I implemented some of your code (please see my updated post), I didn't worry about the text drawing, but this is what I end up with (which is the same issue I have above). http://i.imgur.com/4RREvcp.png
Does this happen to you, too?

Comment: @LBran Again, your logic is off.  You don't need to get the number of rows each time the the custom draw handler is called (ie, your itemCnt loop).  It's called for each row that needs to be painted.  So, when it's called you use the dwItemSpec to determine what row to paint, and, only that row.  The handler will be called again for every row in the control.

Comment: Ahh I see. I removed redundant code, but am still encountering the same issue with the first column not being coloured. Please see EDIT2. Not quite sure where I'm going wrong. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @LBran Are you using the extended CListCtrl style **LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT**?

Comment: Noo I'm not. Should I be? I'll look that up now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void ColorListCtrl::OnCustomDraw(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
    NMLVCUSTOMDRAW *pNMLVCUSTOMDRAW = (NMLVCUSTOMDRAW *) pNMHDR;
    *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;
    switch (pNMLVCUSTOMDRAW->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {   case CDDS_PREPAINT:
            *pResult |= CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
            break;
        case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
            // compare text in column 2
            // set background to special color if matches
            INT nItem = pNMLVCUSTOMDRAW->nmcd.dwItemSpec;
            CString strText = GetItemText(nItem, 2);
            if (strText==_T("No"))  pNMLVCUSTOMDRAW->clrTextBk = RGB(255,0,0);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I implemented your code, and it works fine, except that I am still getting the same issue as above, similar to this: i.imgur.com/4RREvcp.png

Comment: @LBran - Your image shows that the text in the columns are missing, this can only happen with a `FillSolidRect` in the post-paint event as indicated in your code in the EDIT2 of the original post. The requirement of flagging items with a different color is actually quite simple, only need  to change the color in the custom-draw structure, no drawing/filling is needed because the default drawing that follows will handle the rest. Is there any other drawing code somewhere else that you have forgotten ?